# Is it correct to initialise a UITableViewCell using initWithCoder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nib

I am loading a UITableViewCell using,

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlogCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = blogCell;
self.blogCell = nil;
```

where `blogCell` is an outlet to BlogCell.xib

The actual UITableViewCell is of type **BlogCell** which is a subclass of **UITableViewCell**.

In my **BlogCell** class I am using

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

  //initialisation of some cell properties here

  return self;
}
```

Is this correct? Is this the way you would tackle initialisation of a cell loaded from a nib?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That, or in `awakeFromNib`.